# Mapbox runtime crashing issue

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

A/libc: /buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type jni::PendingJavaException" failed

My added libraries ::

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.4.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.7.1'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-building:0.1.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.18.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places:0.2.1'
    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.18.0') {
        transitive = true
    }
```

Can anyone please let me know, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add mapbox-sdk,mapbox-sdk-services, mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer and android-navigation because mapbox-android-navigation-ui include them. But I guess this doesn't solve your issue...